# how to find li with data-rel attribute and it's value in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I find a li element which has data-rel attribute and its value "a1" ?

```
<li class="thumbImg" data-rel="a1">
    <img src="img/a0.jpg" width='150' height="80">
</li>

var relValue = "a1";
$('li[data-rel=relValue]');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation:

```
var relValue = "a1";
$('li[data-rel="' + relValue + '"]');
```

Or in ES2015 and higher, a template literal:

```
        var relValue = "a1";
        $(`li[data-rel="${relValue}"]`);
// Note --^--------------------------^---- those are backticks
```

The inner quotes (`"` in the above) are optional for values that are valid CSS identifiers (like `a1`), but a good idea in case the value may not be (for instance, `a 1`).